# Problems running D3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am learning D3.js, and I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Graphic</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Chrome as a browser on my mac. Am I making an obvious mistake? Thank you!

Comment: what are you trying to do accomplish? You're are just including the library ... you also need to add the code to draw something.

Comment: https://www.dashingd3js.com/

Comment: @Alex_B Hi! I figured it out! :D

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing really wrong per-se with your code, other than the fact that it will do nothing (and I personally would put the 'script src' tag in the head section). You have simply written a HTML document which then loads in the D3.JS Javascript library.

What you now need to do is start using the library by issuing some D3 commands to create HTML/DOM elements from data. There is plenty to read up on the internet (try dashingd3js.com) but to get you started here is a v.simple starter for 10 expanding on your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Column Chart</title>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartarea"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Some random data
    var data = [0.27, 0.5, 0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.21, 0.25, 0.94, 0.04, 1.00];

    var svg = d3.select('#chartarea')
        .selectAll('div')
        .data(data)
    .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'bar')
        .style('height', function (d) {
            return d * 400 + 'px';
        });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above should create a v.simple column chart using HTML DIV's. You can then move on to more advanced implementations to generate SVG components.

Also see example here:
http://bl.ocks.org/jamesleesaunders/260cf482c8a56d49dfa6